# Display object data in select dropdown using ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use angularJS along with Symfony2.
For starters, m trying to display the object's text property as options in a simple dropdown list using ng-options.
Here's the HTML

```
    <div ng-app="demoAddList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedProgram"  ng-options="programofinterest.id as programofinterest.text for programofinterest in programofinterests">
            </select>
        </div>
<p>Try to add the same item twice, and you will get an error message.</p>
```

Here's the script

```
var app = angular.module("programDropdown", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.programofinterests = [
            {id: '0', text: 'Masters - Information Systems Management'},
            {id: '1', text: 'Masters - Software Engineering'},
            {id: '2', text: 'Masters - Computer Security'},
            {id: '3', text: 'Bachelors of Computer Science'},
            {id: '4', text: 'Exchange Program'},
            {id: '5', text: 'Study Abroad'},
            {id: '6', text: 'Scientific Summer School'},
            {id: '7', text: 'French Summer School'},
            {id: '8', text: 'ME - Global IT Management'},
            {id: '9', text: 'ME -  Software Development and Multimedia'},
            {id: '10', text: 'ME - Systems, Networks and Security'}
        ];
});
```

However the result is empty dropdown. Have a look at the top-left corner of the screenshot 
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You have not included jquery also the code need to be compiled since browser do not understand require keyword

Comment: are you talking about `<script type="text/javascript" src="/EPITACRM/web/bundles/epitacrm/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to fix the "JQuery" and "require" issues. This will probably also fix your Angular issue, though not guaranteed since Angular normally does not need JQuery. It has a kind of lightweight JQuery embedded.

You might put a break-point in the controller and see if the debugger gets there.

Comment: The debugger wasn't really inspecting the dropdown element.

Comment: I have no idea why the dropdown is not getting populated. Any idea if I've made any syntax mistake?

Comment: But the errors previously shown may prevent AngularJS to work properly. I really recommend fixing those issues first.

Comment: I tried copy pasting a simple AngularJS app from w3schools, in the same page, it worked just fine. M not sure why this isn't

Comment: Maybe you can try putting a break-point in your controller and see if it gets there. I still think you should sort out the JQuery and Require issues...